# Grabbing array values from JSON with React

Tags: json, reactjs

I have an app that allows a user to search the Spotify API for artists, albums, etc. I'm able to make a request and get the response, but having trouble grabbing the values from the response to display.

**App.jsx**

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchTerm: '',
      userData: []
    }
  }

  // Get data from spotify
  getUserData(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q='+this.state.searchTerm+'&type=playlist',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
      console.log(data.playlists.items);
        this.setState({userData: data.playlists.items});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
      this.setState({searchTerm: null});
        alert(error);
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
  handleFormSubmit(searchTerm){
    this.setState({searchTerm: searchTerm}, function(){
      this.getUserData();
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUserData();
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
          <Search onFormSubmit = {this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)} />
          <Songs {...this.state}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**Songs.jsx**

```
class Songs extends Component{

  render(){
    return(
        <div className="panel panel-default panel-order">
          <div className="panel-body">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-1"><img src={this.props.userData.images} /></div>
              <div className="col-md-11">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-12">
                    <span><strong>Track Name: {this.props.userData.name}</strong></span>
                    <br /> Tracks:{this.props.userData.tracks}
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-12">
                    Type: <p>{this.props.userData.type}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Songs
```

This is a screenshot of a sample response. 
[image]
I should be able to grab the `name`, `url` from the `images` array, etc, but not able to loop through them.

Comment: you want to iterate the image array and get the urls ? object of image array doesn't contain the name i think.

Comment: I want to be able to grab the image urls, plus the name(which is at the same level as the images array).

Comment: @MayankShukla - I want to be able to print the name, which should be "Imagine Dragons Best Of" in this case.

Comment: `userData` is an Array of Objects. So you can't access array as object notation in your `Songs.jsx` file. Iterate through the array. Use `.map` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of your data is this:

```
playlist:{
  items:[
    {
      name: 'a',
      images: [
        {
          url: 'aa',
          href: 'aa'
        },
        {
          url: 'ab',
          href: 'ab'
        },
        {
          url: 'ac',
          href: 'ac'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'b',
      images: [
        {
          url: 'ba',
          href: 'ba'
        },
        {
          url: 'bb',
          href: 'bb'
        },
        {
          url: 'bc',
          href: 'bc'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]    
}
```

To get the names, first you need to iterate the `userData` array (it is an array of object) then inside that use another map on images to get the value of urls.

Write it like this to access the name and url values:

```
class Songs extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          {this.props.userData.map(el => {
              return(
                <div key={el.name}>
                    {el.name}
                    {el.images.map(img => {
                        return <img alt='temp' src={img.url} key={img.url}/>
                    })}
                </div>
              )
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Check the working snippet:

```js
class Songs extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          {this.props.userData.map(el => {
              return(
                <div key={el.name}>
                    {el.name}
                    {el.images.map(img => {
                        return <img alt='temp' src={img.url} key={img.url}/>
                    })}
                </div>
              )
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

var playlist={
  items:[
    {
      name: 'a',
      images: [
        {
          url: 'aa',
          href: 'aa'
        },
        {
          url: 'ab',
          href: 'ab'
        },
        {
          url: 'ac',
          href: 'ac'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'b',
      images: [
        {
          url: 'ba',
          href: 'ba'
        },
        {
          url: 'bb',
          href: 'bb'
        },
        {
          url: 'bc',
          href: 'bc'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}

ReactDOM.render(<Songs userData={playlist.items}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, try it

```
    class App extends Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          searchTerm: '',
          userData: []
        }
      }

      // Get data from spotify
      getUserData(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q='+this.state.searchTerm+'&type=playlist',
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
          console.log(data.playlists.items);
            this.setState({userData: data.playlists.items.map((val) => {
                name: val.name,
                href: val.href
            })});
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, error){
          this.setState({searchTerm: null});
            alert(error);
          }.bind(this)
        });
      }
      handleFormSubmit(searchTerm){
        this.setState({searchTerm: searchTerm}, function(){
          this.getUserData();
        });
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        this.getUserData();
      }

      render(){
        return(
            <div>
              <Search onFormSubmit = {this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)} />
              <Songs {...this.state}/>
            </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default App
```

Check the ajax call part and manipulate it as per your needs

And if your items are not in json format then you might need to do

```
JSON.parse()
```

on them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error which I can't trace down. I should be able to grab the value for the `url` within the `images` array. I've updated the screenshot of the json for clarity.